# Heading Div Not Working on smaller devices

Tags: css

Please bear with me...though I've been stalking Stack Overflow for years and have had hundreds of my questions answered, this is my first post.

My main content column is 880px. Right above it are the H1 and breadcrumbs which look fine on a desktop. But when I shrink the screen size or look at it on a mobile device, the text is not wrapping or centering. It's off the screen.

Here is the code in my child theme (the width in the main theme is 590, not 880):

```
#heading, .archive .cat_head {
    float:right; 
    width: 880px; 
    text-align: center; 
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
```

When I remove `text-align: center;` it all works on mobile, but not on laptop.

Any thoughts on how I can get the heading/breadcrumbs to center in the 880px space on all devices? Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you! I think that did it. I had to move back to my original 960 width since I had a lot of other issues but I think that will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the `width:880px` use percentage. Set width to 100%. `width:100%;`